# Is it possible to create a second user (User B) automatically after a first user (User A) has fulfilled a registration form?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created a wordpress page with a front-end registration form. I'll have two types of users, let's call them "**Parents**" and "**Childs**". For each Parent I will have a Child but I don't want the childs to use the registration form.

In other words, I want a registration form for the "Parents". When the Parents create their user, I want it to automatically create another user for the Child. For example: A is a Parent, he registers himself and gets the user **ParentA**, at the same time the user **ChildPA** is also created. Is this possible to do?

btw I don't need any information from the child, I just need the Child user to be created everytime a Parent user is created.

At the moment I'm using the plugin Piotnet Addons For Elementor (PAFE) to create my registration form

Comment: This is possible to do, however, how are you going to get the email address for the second user?

Comment: I don't want them to get confirmation emails or anything like that. WP allows me to create users with dummy emails like myemail@email.com so I was thinking of something like that.

Comment: ok, You can use this hook to detect when a user registers and create a function to register new user: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/ . However, you will need to implement some sort off BREAK after you register second user other wise you will be stuck in a loop.